# I met an issue when I tried to test my smart contract, which is :AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 17

Tags: solidity, javascript, chai

This is smart contract.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint256 favoriteNumber;
    Person public person = Person({favoriteNumber: 2, name: "Rocco"});

    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public virtual {
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
    }

    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256) {
        return favoriteNumber;
    }

    //pure和view不消耗gas,pure是不可读不可改，view是可读不可改

    mapping(string => uint256) public nametofavoritenumber;

    struct Person {
        uint256 favoriteNumber;
        string name;
    } //结构体

    Person[] public manyPeople;

    function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        Person memory newPerson = Person(_favoriteNumber, _name); 
        manyPeople.push(newPerson);
        nametofavoritenumber[_name] = _favoriteNumber;
    }
}
```

This is test.js

```
const { assert } = require("chai")
const { ethers } = require("hardhat")
require("chai")

describe("SimpleStorage", function () {
    let simpleStorage
    let simpleStorageFactory
    beforeEach(async function () {
        simpleStorageFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("SimpleStorage")
        simpleStorage = await simpleStorageFactory.deploy()
    }) 
    it("Shoud start with a favorite number of 0", async function () {
        const currentValue = await simpleStorage.retrieve()
        const expectedValue = "0"
        //expect assert
        assert.equal(currentValue.toString(), expectedValue) 
    })
    it("Should update when we call store", async function () {
        const expectedValue = "7"
        const transactionResponse = await simpleStorage.store(expectedValue)
        await transactionResponse.wait(1)

        const currentValue = await simpleStorage.retrieve()
        assert.equal(currentValue.toString(), expectedValue)
        //expect(CurrentValue.toString()).to.equal(expectedValue)
    })
    it("Should update when we call addperson", async function () {
        const person = {
            name: "L",
            favoriteNumber: 17,
        }
        const transactionResponse = await simpleStorage.addPerson(
            person.name,
            person.favoriteNumber,
        )
        await transactionResponse.wait(1)
        const newPerson = await simpleStorage.manyPeople(0)
        assert.equal(newPerson.name, person.name)
        assert.equal(newPerson.favoriteNumber, person.favoriteNumber)

        const favorNum = await simpleStorage.nametofavoritenumber[person.name]
        assert.equal(favorNum, person.favoriteNumber)
    })


})
```

This is the error:

```
 1) SimpleStorage
   Should update when we call addperson:
 AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 17
  at Context.<anonymous> (test/test-deploy.js:45:16)
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5
```

The line 45(where the error is) is `assert.equal(favorNum, person.favoriteNumber)`.But I dont know why it did't equal 17. Where is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line:

```
    const favorNum = await simpleStorage.nametofavoritenumber[person.name]
```

You are calling a smart contract function. It means you need to use parenthesis () to wrap the argument.

```
    const favorNum = await simpleStorage.nametofavoritenumber(person.name)
```

keep in mind that when you fetch the data from a mapping in the solidity contract itself, then only you use square brackets [] otherwise whenever you query the mapping from outside of the contract whether JS or any other contract you need to use the parenthesis. Because it becomes a normal function call.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I learnt that every public state variables in solidity will automatically generate a function getter. What I tried to do was call this function. Is it right?

Comment: Yes exactly, calling the mapping from outside the contract works like a normal view function call. The square brackets are only needed inside the contract. 

Do mark the answer if that solved the issue.